# PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula

Tags: salesforce

I try use this formula in SlaesForce, but I am getting this error " PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula"

```
if(AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Closed"),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Test"))), test=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRIORVALUE can only be used on formulas in Workflow rules where the workflow rule is set to "Whenever the object is created or edited."  So if you're trying to use this in a formula field, you won't succeed -- try doing it with a workflow rule and a field update and setting a standard field with the value instead.